# Universal Analytics upgrade works only intermittently

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Update: fixed! problem wasn't with UA. old GA numbers were out because previous installer had put UA code on multiple sites.

**What I've done/The Problem**

Okay so I am testing an upgrade for http://www.neighbourhoodwatchscotland.co.uk from async Google Analytics to Universal.

I set up Google Tag Manager and followed the Luna Metrics guide to upgrading using that (this one http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/25/upgrade-universal-analytics-guide/).

Currently stuck at the testing phase and running GA and UA in parallel. Been doing this several days now and UA seems to only see 1/2 to a 1/3 of the sessions/users/pageviews that GA does for the same days.

**what I tried to do to fix it**

Whenever I test it it seems to work fine (i.e. in real time). Checked that it was indeed firing on all pages. Tried checking for any weird filters but there are none.

I tried using preview/debug in Google Tag Manager but the UA tag seems to fire pretty consistently. I thought there might be a hint if it was recording page views on some pages not others but there isn't a pattern there.

Homepage page views for example are recorded by both GA and UA but UA only records about a 1/2 to a 1/3 of what GA does. Neither GA nor UA seems to discriminate by country/browser etc which I also looked into for a hint.

Google Tag Manager code seems to be in the right place at the start of the body tag and I don't think it has undergone any customization. I checked it against the one in GTM settings and looks the same.

Last thing I thought it might was due to the fact that we 301 the root domain to www. so neighbourghoodwatchscotland.co.uk becomes www.neighbourhoodwatchscotland.co.uk. I thought that maybe it might be trying to stop self referrals and not showing any sessions that redirect in this way but I did a test and in real time it seems to see them.

Have googled this a bunch including here but hard to search for the problem on account on it being intermittent. I had a few weird extra tags in GTM to try and get auto event tracking going and thought that might be interfering so removed those but haven't seen any improvement.

Here's the GTM code that's in.

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PG3KK2"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PG3KK2');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Here's the old async that's also in

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29660524-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Here's what is in the installation instructions. Seems same to me I don't think developers made any mistakes putting it in:

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PG3KK2"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PG3KK2');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Any ideas are very welcome. Thanks for your time and expertise.

Edited to add: I just realised that it's possible the old async counts are the ones that are out of course ... don't know how to check that though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may have place in account/resource/view settings in GA interface. For example - in classic GA you could set another time zone than in Universal GA, that`s enough. I couldn`t give all examples - try check all settings. It`s a first thought.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i should have mentioned that i checked the view settings previously. The time difference was different (GMT versus London) but it was only one hour and since i got them the same no improvement. Checked property settings now and only difference was one had 'demographic and interest reports' enabled but that shouldn't make the difference. Also it shouldn't even work because Advertiser Features isn't enabled. Thanks. p.s. they are both under the same account

Comment: Update to say I checked to see if it could be session timeout but it's not that

Comment: Another update to say that i've found the best hint so far in that the avg. session duration is massively different (3.40 for UA v 1.32 for GA) ...

Comment: Just wanted to update to say that I fixed the problem. UA was fine, old GA numbers were dodgy because developers put the code on multiple sites. Discovered this by looking in the content report, confirmed it by setting up an advanced segment for hostname. As soon as you click in the box it autosuggests all the other sites that have the UA code on them.

Hope this helps others!